# What is the purpose of Math.max in the context of array.slice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I"m doing some w3 coding exercises, and one example gives this:

```
return array.slice(Math.max(array.length - n, 0));
```

What is the purpose of Math.max here. I know it gives the max value of the given parameters `(length -n , 0)`. But, confused why you cannot just use `array.length - n`?

Comment: How about providing the objective of the exercise where it is used ?

Comment: `Array.slice` with a negative index indicates an offset from the end of the array. `slice(-2)` extracts the last two elements in the array.

If `array.length - n` is less than `0`, i.e. any negative number, it still returns `0`, which would not slice the array at all, but return a full copy, a negative number would slice from the end, which isn't wanted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code produces a new array with the `n` last elements of `arr`.

However, `n` might be greater than the length of the array. In this case, `Math.max` ensures `slice` will be called with `0` instead of a negative number.

This might be problematic because when `slice` is called with a negative number, it adds the length of the array to it.

For example,

```
var array = [1, 2, 3],
    n = 4;
array.slice(array.length - n); // [3]
array.slice(Math.max(array.length - n, 0)); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Note this is only problematic if `l < n < 2 l`, where `l` is the length of the array.

- If `n <= l`, then `l - n >= 0`. `Math.max` is not needed.
- If `n >= 2 l` and `n > 0`, then `l - n <= -n/2 < 0`. Therefore `slice` will sum `l`, but `2 l - n` is still not positive. Then `slice` will use `0`. `Math.max` is not needed.
- If `n = 2 l = 0`, then `l - n = 0`. `Math.max` is not needed.
- If `l < n < 2 l`, then `l - n < 0`. Therefore `slice` will sum `l`, and `2 l - n > 0`. Problem! `Math.max` is needed.

Answer (score 4):

The `Math.max` here gives you the greater of `array.length - n` *and* 0.

`array.length - n` may be less than 0. Using a negative number would likely cause `.slice` to give you an unexpected result.

Thus, you are guaranteed to always be returned a "good" number.

Comment: Is there any reference that `.slice` with a negative argument gives unexpected behavior. As far as I know, it always returns the last *k* items given the argument *-k*.

Comment: You're correct! However, given that the context seems to be an introductory coding tutorial, I'm assuming that getting the last `k` items would not be what this particular user expects.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is greater than `array.length`, the returned result will be negative.  By saying *return the greater value of this subtraction and zero*, you make sure to never return a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Math.max returns the largest values from its parameters. In this case it looks like 0 is a default value and the author wanted to filter negative values since `n` can be greater than array.length.

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not know the context of `n`, it could be possible that `n` is larger than `array.length`. For instance if the array has length `4`, `n` could be `5`. Now a peculiar thing happens when the argument of `.slice` is strictly negative:

```
$ node
> x=[1,2,3,4]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
> x.slice(-1)
[ 4 ]
```

(using `node`, a JavaScript shell)

If the argument is `-k`, it retains the last `k` items. This can be undesired behavior. So using `math.max` one ensures the argument is positive and either no items are removed or the first *l* are removed with *l* being `array.length-n`.